# Physics.Raycast and Physics.RaycastAll Have Different Results For Custom Layer

Tags: unity-game-engine

As the title mentions, I am receiving different results from `bool Physics.Raycast(...)` and `RayCastHit[] Physics.RaycastAll(...)`, aside from the obvious fact that the methods return different parameters. `Raycast` is returning true, implying that the ray hits at least one target. `RaycastAll` is returning 0 results. Interestingly, `Raycast` *always* returns true in my short scene, and `RaycastAll` *always* returns false.

I have a custom layer I am trying to string- I've named it "ClusterGoal" and it is on layer 9.
`Ray goalRay = new Ray(rayOrigin, agent.destination);`

`RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.RaycastAll(goalRay, 100f, LayerMask.GetMask("ClusterGoal"), QueryTriggerInteraction.Collide);`

`bool hit = Physics.Raycast(goalRay, 100f, LayerMask.GetMask("ClusterGoal"), QueryTriggerInteraction.Collide);`

The above to lines results in the following logs.

`RaycastAll hit 0 target(s) using mask 512 at location on its way from (13.8, 0.1, 11.8) to (1.0, 0.0, 0.3) from distance 8.164141`

`Raycast hit a target using mask 512 at location on its way from (13.8, 0.1, 11.8) to (1.0, 0.0, 0.3) from distance 8.164141`

As an experiment, I tried inverting my layer mask on RaycastAll and found that it successfully hit every object except the one tagged as a cluster goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raycasting happens from the bottom of the game object. In my case, the object I was trying to raycast to was floating in the air and its transform listed it's Y-axis as 0. For some reason when I was calling `agent.destination`, The y-value was 0 instead of the expected 1.

The two solution I came up with were to move the collider on my ray destination to the ground, or to move the game object itself to the ground.